# Angular 12 Regional Environment Switcher

Tags: angular

I have a simple angular website which displays various products, simple lists returned from databases, originally just based in the UK but now another due to come out in France, so I have two APIs a uk.domain and a fr.domain.

I'd like to use the same frontend rather than deploying two separate frontends, with the switch only changing the products that are loaded on two of the pages.

Along with this I also have environment.dev.ts and environment.prod.ts files containing the necessary endpoints.

Ideally I'd have a button to switch between the regions once this has been deployed.

Is this possible or bad practice, if so, what would be the best solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the datamodel is the same for both apis, you can do this with a simple switch in the ui. Later there multiple ways to get the users location so you can automatically guess the right api. For example: [geolocator api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API)

Example for switching the endpoint:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  apiEndpoints: {
    uk: 'https://uk.domain/api',
    fr: 'https://fr.domain/api'
  }
};

export class ProductService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getProducts(region: 'uk' | 'fr') {
    const apiEndpoint = environment.apiEndpoints[region];
    return this.http.get(`${apiEndpoint}/products`);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but not necessarily user's location, I'd want it to be a choice where the user can select from France or the UK.

Comment: so you want just to switch the api based on userinput ?

Comment: Yes, switch which environmental variables are being used depending on user input, site wide until the other option is selected.

Comment: i've given you an example

Comment: If you want to avoid keeping the parameter type in sync with the supported regions in the environment file, you could use `getProducts(region: keyof typeof environment.apiEndpoints) { }`.